# R function/package to conduct Hausman test for panel count data after the use of pglm r function

Tags: r, panel-data, poisson

does anyone know how to conduct Hausman test with R software for panel count data regression after the use of pglm function/package please?

What I would like to try is, instead of using the count data, to use the proportion to avoid using panel count data regression. Is it a good way? My response variable is the total number of students in schools in a city.

Comment: This question is better suited to [stats.se]. I have voted to migrate your question over there.